# DFS: Use Dictionary to store visited states VS. array

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, matrix, depth-first-search

I'm counting the probability of staying on an N by N chessboard after K steps, given that the starting position is r, c. Here's my code:

```
def knightProbability(self, N, K, r, c):
    # dfs.
    answer = 0
    dp = [[[-1] * N]*N] * (K+1)
    # dfs with memoization.
    self.dic = {}
    return self.dfs(N, K, r, c, dp) # Starting at r, c, what's the probability of staying on board after k moves.



def dfs(self, N, k, r, c, dp):
    offsets = [(-1, -2), (-1, 2), (-2, -1), (-2, 1), (1, -2), (1, 2), (2, -1), (2, 1)]
    answer = 0.0

    if k == 0:
        return 1.0

    '''if dp[k][r][c] >= 0:
        return dp[k][r][c]'''
    if str(k) + ":" + str(r) + ":" + str(c) in self.dic:
        return self.dic[str(k) + ":" + str(r) + ":" + str(c)]

    for offset in offsets:
        new_r = r + offset[0]
        new_c = c + offset[1]
        if new_r > -1 and new_r < N and new_c > -1 and new_c < N:
            answer += self.dfs(N, k-1, new_r, new_c, dp) * 1.0 / 8 # with k-1 steps, what's the probability?
    '''dp[k][r][c] = answer'''
    self.dic[str(k) + ":" + str(r) + ":" + str(c)] = answer
    return answer
```

It's a simple dfs. When I use a dictionary to store and retrieve visited states (k, r, c) like I'm doing now, it works. However, if I use a k by N by N array to store and retrive them, I'm not getting the correct answers. Any ideas why? The commented part is the storing/ retrieving from the array parts I'm talking about, which should be doing the same thing as the current code.

Comment: `dp = [[[None] * N]*N] * (K+1)` doesn't do what you think. See what this does: `dp = [[[None] * 2]*2] * 3; dp[0][0].append(1); print(dp)`

Comment: @PM2Ring wow, I see... Thanks! So I have to use for _ in range(n), etc.

Comment: Exactly. The top answer in the linked question is pretty good. You may also find this article helpful: [Facts and myths about Python names and values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.